# Serving wine/drinks

Tags: expressions

You're pouring wine for your friend.If your friend can only drink a little.What expression would you use that means"tell me if this amount of wine is ok for you"?

Answer (score 4):

The classic expression is, when you begin pouring, you say "Tell me when." When the other person says "When!" or "That's good!" or just about anything, that's when you stop pouring.

Comment: +1 Or *say when* for short.